# How to change order of mail folders?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I have this function for getting user folders.

```
function getUserFolders(callback) {
  getAccessToken(function(accessToken) {
    if (accessToken) {
      // Create a Graph client
      var client = MicrosoftGraph.Client.init({
        authProvider: done => {
          // Just return the token
          done(null, accessToken);
        }
      });

      // Get all folders
      client
        .api("/me/MailFolders")
        .orderby("")
        .get((err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            callback(null, err);
          } else {
            callback(res.value);
          }
        });
      console.log(client);
    } else {
      var error = { responseText: "Could not retrieve access token" };
      callback(null, error);
    }
  });
}
```

When I get a response back, the order of folders is:

[image: order of folders]

I have read documentation and couldn't find how to change order of folders. The order i would like to have is the same one as on outlook. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: have you tried removing the `orderby` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot retrieve folders in the order a user organized them in a given client.

I'm also not sure what you expect to get from `.orderby("")`. Unless you provide a field to order by, it won't know how you want to sort them.